# How to calculate Google Earth polygon size in pixels

Tags: python, google-maps, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, kml

OS X 10.7.5, Python 2.7, GE 7.1.2.2041

I have some .kml data that includes a moderately large number of polygons. Each polygon has an image associated with it. I want to use each image in a `<GroundOverlay>` mode with its associated polygon.

The raw images are all a bit larger than the polygons. I can easily resize the images with Python's Image Library (PIL), but the amount of missizing is not consistent across the entire set. Some are as good as only ~5% larger, and some go up to ~20% larger.

What I would like to do is either find (or calculate) the approximate sizes of the polygons in pixels so that I can automate the resizing of their associated images with that data.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm guessing the polygons aren't rectangular? One thought that comes to mind is to use shapely (or other library) and calculate the area of the polygon, then use the width/height ratio of the image to scale it to that area. Just a thought.

Comment: @daveydave400: Actually the polygons are rectangular enough that a height and width in pixels at any place would probably work.

Comment: So what you're saying is I should have said that in the form of an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the width and height of the polygon/rectangle in longitude and latitude coordinates. Then use the ratio of that rectangle to the image size and it should fit.

**Edit**: I should note that depending on where your images are going to show up you might need some special math for the dateline (-180 to 180) or prime-meridian (0 to 360).